# How can i access parent window domain into child window (window.open) if both windows are on cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help in cross domain communication between window.

window.open();

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is ***not possible***.

> All modern browsers do now allow to do this.

---

***Exception*** :

If you are having control over both domains i.e. you have control over both parent and child window code. You can use like this on the child domain to access parent
`window.opener.functionname(a,b)` or `window.opener.buttonid.name`

You need to know about header `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to allow cross domain scripting on the other domains where you don't have control over parent or child windows domain and they are different.

Comment: If you control both, postMessage api is also easy to use